# How much memory should I allocate for host OS when virtualizing

Tags: virtualization, memory

I would like to buy a dedicated server and virtualize it. Details:

Host OS Ubuntu 12.04 server OS
Setting up 3 VMs. 2 serving web applicaitons with php/Mysql + nginx and 1 running bugzilla.

With that said how much RAM memory should I allocate for the host OS. The host OS will not be used for anything other than managing the VMs. Please let me know if I need to supply more info. I am planning to use KVM for virtualization.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop or Ubumtu 12.04 Server OS?

Comment: @tombull89 Ubuntu 12.04 Server OS

Comment: How many concurrent users have you estimated? have you considered to provision nginx in a different VLAN (and a different VM) that MySQL?

Comment: @dawud - nginx/php-fpm/mysql would reside in a guest VM. They will not live in the Host OS

Comment: Note that unused RAM on a VM host is not necessarily a waste. As a Host OS, Linux will use any unused RAM for disk cache, so what the VM think is disk access may in fact be served by a much faster RAM access on the host.

Answer (score 0):

You would need enough RAM for 3 VMs and some more for the host.

### For the host

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-System_requirements.html

> 2GB of RAM plus additional RAM for guests.

### For the guests

This depends on your needs. Most entry level VMs have around 1GB of RAM nowadays so that should server as a good starting point if you're not sure.

If you wanted to keep things lean (and your server won't have a lot of visitors/users) you may get away with less (you could try for 512MB RAM). Keep in mind the moment you start installing software, and getting visitors/users you'll need to cater for more RAM.

Until you do your own tests you won't really have a real indication of how much RAM each machine will need, and of course this will change as your server usage changes.

Here are some good questions to consider:

- How many visitors will the server need to handle?
- What sort of scripts will the server be running (custom scripts or add-ons may increase the amount of grunt required).
- Will you have big databases or datasets?
- Will you need to do things like AntiVirus Scanning, Backups or Maintenance tasks (these will consume RAM)
- Will you take advantage of software like Varnish (this may help reduce the amount of work PHP has to do, thus reduce your need for RAM on that box)

Comment: I am trying to find out the RAM neccessity about the Host Os and not the guest OS.

Comment: I have explained the requirements for the host.